# Lost all permissions to hard drive in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, permissions

I had to share my laptop with someone, so I tried to change the access permissions of my storage drive, while windows is on my SSD. But somehow I lost all permissions to my drive.

After trying all icacls techniques, I did a reset and a fresh install, and it still doesn't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: what happens when you "click change above" as you are prompted?

Comment: Did you try to change the owner to yourself from the screen in your image? What happened?

Comment: As an Administrator change the owner of the drive. By default all users have full permission on non-system drives

Comment: While it's easy to write that you tried "***all** icacls techniques*" it would better if you can include what you tried and what the resulting error/messege was.

Answer (score 2):

The reason reset and fresh install (of your OS on another drive) didn't help is because those aren't OS permissions, they are file system NTFS permissions which are stored as part of the file system on the drive itself.

To reset the NTFS permissions for everything on the drive (and this would've worked regardless if your OS had been reset or not), Open Commend Prompt as Administrator and first take ownership on the files/drive with the `TAKEOWN` command:

```
TAKEOWN /F E:\ /R /D Y
```

Once you have ownership, then you can reset the permissions using `icacls`:

```
icacls "E:\" /reset /T /Q /C
```

Comment: Small addition to this already good answer: this solution would even have worked without reinstalling windows.

Comment: Indeed, I implied this with my opening paragraph, but I'll add it in explicitly.